# Pushing values from a $_Get query to a value using implode

Tags: php, get

I am attempting to use a for loop or for each loop to push the values from a get query to another variable. May I have some help with this approach?

Ok here is where I am:

```
for ($i = 0 ; i < $_GET['delete']; i++) {

    $_jid [] = $_GET['delete'];  
 }
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Please post your code, the areas you are concerned about. We can absolutely help with specifics.

Comment: Are you _appending_ values from `$_GET['delete']` onto the contents of `$_jid` (does `$_jid` already have values in it)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski $_jid is a newly declared array that I am attempting to take the posts from $_GET['delete'] and place in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a loop here.  If `$_jid` already is an array containing some values, consider just merging it with `$_GET['delete']`.

```
if (is_array($_jid)) {
  $_jid = array_merge($_jid, $_GET['delete']);
}
```

If `$_jid` is not an array and doesn't exist except as a container for `$_GET['delete']` you do can just assign the array. There is no need to loop at all.

```
$_jid = $_GET['delete'];
```

Of course in that case, you don't even need to copy it. You can just use `$_GET['delete']` directly, in any context you planned to read from `$_jid`.

---

Update:

If the contents of `$_GET['delete']` are originally `923,936`, that is *not* an array to begin with, but rather a string. If you want an array out of it, you need to `explode()` it on assignment:

```
$_jid = explode(',', $_GET['delete']);
```

But if you intend to `implode()` it in the end anyway, there's obviously no need to do that. You already have exactly the comma-delimited string you want.

Comment: When I use $_jid = $_GET['delete']; then a var_dump with an implode, I get a "NULL" That was why I was trying to figure why wasnt it not outputting correctly

Comment: This is exactly what I have and get an "NULL" $_jid  = $_GET['delete'];   
 
  var_dump(implode(",", $_jid));

Comment: @infomatic: Well, what happens when you `var_dump($_GET['delete'])`?

Comment: I get the values outputted with a comma between. example string(7) "923,926"

Comment: So what is the content of `$_GET['delete']` in the first place? `print_r($_GET['delete']);`  If it is an array, assigning it directly to `$_jid` will result in a copy of the same array.

Comment: @infomatic "923,926" are the original content of `$_GET['delete']`? That isn't an array, it's a string.

Comment: Oh I just realised using a implode would return a null but an explode output the value

Comment: @infomatic So do you have what you need then? I think I covered everything above.

Comment: Oh yes I do, sorry about that

Comment: A follow up question: Say I wanted to use the result of this explode in a foreach, would this be appropriate: $_jid  = explode("," , $_GET['delete']);   
  
  foreach($_jid as $value){
   echo $value;
           
  }

Comment: This doesnt echo a value - This is quite puzzling

Comment: To debug an array which doesn't do what you expect, always `print_r($_jid)`. Also `print_r(explode(',', $_GET['delete']))` If `$_jid` is an array, the loop will work.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you do a `var_dump($_GET)`, the variable `$_GET` is a hashmap.
You can easily use a `foreach` loop to look through every member of it :

```
foreach($_GET as $get) // $get will successively take the values of $_GET
{
  echo $get."<br />\n"; // We print these values
}
```

The code above will print the value of the `$_GET` members (you can try it with a blank page and dull `$_GET` values, as "http://yoursite.usa/?get1=stuff&get2=morestuff")

Instead of a `echo`, you can put the $_GET values into an array (or other variables) :

```
$array = array(); // Creating an empty array
$i = 0; // Counter
foreach($_GET as $get)
{
  $array[$i] = $get; // Each $_GET value is store in a $array slot
  $i++;
}
```

In PHP, `foreach` is quite useful and very easy to use.
However, you can't use a `for` for `$_GET` because it's a hashmap, not an array (in fact, you can, but it's much more complicated).

Hope I helped